# Location of the file downloaded on android using ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make a file download with ionic 3. This is the code that I use:

```
public download(file_name){
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.png').then((entry) => {
  const url = this.urlServe +'/documents/'+ this.name + this.id +'/'+ file_name;

    this.view.dismiss({retornar:entry.toURL()});
  }, (error) => {
    this.view.dismiss({retornar:error.source});
  });
}
```

The file supposedly if it is downloaded but when I see the URL that the Trasfer file returns to me is this:

```
file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/file.png
```

This location can not be located anywhere on the device, I use Blu vivo XL, I would like it to be downloaded to the device downloads folder. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be very useful, thank you very much

Comment: `this.file.dataDirectory`. Look if `this.file` has other members.

Comment: I was able to find the file, and it was changing the file member. Many thanks!!!