# where was file location downloaded in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm try to download file in ionic5 using this code

```
downloadImages() {
let photo_name = this.util.getPhotoName(this.contacts.rows.item(this.counter).person_fullname);
let url = encodeURI(this.imagePathUrl + photo_name + "?r=" + Math.round(Math.random() * 999999));
let local_path = this.util.getLocalPath();
let fileUrl = local_path + this.paramPro.getPhotoFileName() + "/" + photo_name;
this.fileTransfer.download(url, fileUrl).then(entry => {
console.log('download : ', entry);
  if (this.counter == this.contacts.rows.length-1) {
    this.loading.dismiss().catch(() => {});
    this.presentDownloadFinishAlert(this.paramPro.getMessage('title'), this.paramPro.getMessage('download_complete'));
  } else {
    this.counter++;
    this.downloadImages();
  }
}).catch(e => {
  if (this.counter == this.contacts.rows.length-1) {
    this.loading.dismiss().catch(() => {}); 
    this.presentDownloadFinishAlert(this.paramPro.getMessage('title'), this.paramPro.getMessage('download_complete'));
  } else {
    this.counter++;
    this.downloadImages();
  }
});
```

}

and i got console.log

```
file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/photo_mg/%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A3%20%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%A8%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B5.png
```

it is same issue as [Location of the file downloaded on android using ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292155/location-of-the-file-downloaded-on-android-using-ionic)
i also put this code in config.xml

```
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
```

and put this code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

it still doesn't work where was file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files in my phone ? I find it with windows explorer find files, and i not found it.

Comment: Look inside `Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files` starting from the internal storage root of your device

Comment: thanks you so much for responsing. Here Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files. i'm not found any folder, files inside it. but my code checkdir, createdir was correctly create and found dir. I was very curious.

Answer (score 0):

finally, found the answer. ionic cordova need to use Ionic.webView.convertFileSrc to
convert file

from file:///path/to/device/file

to http://host:port/prefix/path/to/device/file   <--- to display in html

see doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/core-concepts/webview#file-protocol

you can't browse files directly in your phone ?? (not sure)

```
this.fileTransfer.download(url, fileUrl).then(entry => {
   let win: any = window;
   this.safeURL = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(entry.toURL());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not especially for your need but I can provide a larger solution. I create a cache service for Ionic and it includes file saving and checking

```
  private win: any = window;

  public async checkFile(fileUrl) {

    let stringURL = String(fileUrl);
    let fileName = stringURL.split('//')[1].replace(/\//g, '-');
    let directory;

    if (this.platform.is("desktop")) {
      return fileUrl;
    }
    if (this.platform.is("android")) {
      directory = this.file.dataDirectory;
    }
    if (this.platform.is("ios")) {
      directory = this.file.dataDirectory;
    }
    return this.file.checkFile(directory, fileName)
      .then(
        async result => {
          if (result) {
            return this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(directory + fileName);
          } else {
            return fileUrl;
          }
        }
      )
      .catch(
        async err => {
          //FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR
          if (err.code == 1) {
            let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
            fileTransfer.download(fileUrl, directory + fileName, true)
              .then(
                result => {
                }
              )
              .catch(
                error => {
                  console.error(error);
                  throw error;
                }
              )
          }
          return fileUrl;

        }
      )


  }
```

If you log directory in checkFile function or result in catch part of the function you will see where the file is

You can check project and code from here : https://gitlab.com/demarkelabs/sanalmarketuygulamam/ionic-app/-/blob/master/src/app/cache.service.ts