# ionic 5 PDFTron Webviewer doesn't have access to file URLs because of browser security restrictions

Tags: ionic5, pdftron

I try to integrate the PDFTron API in an ionic 5 application in which I download the pdf from the server, store them on the phone and then open them with the API
currently when I put the files in the assets folder of my ionic project, the api opens it without problem
but when I download the file to the phone memory and try to open it with the API by passing the link of this file, I have the following error (on the image)

[image]

Is there a way to fix this or store the downloaded files in the assets folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who encounter this same problem, just convert the native url (Ex file: ///storage/emulated/0/USL/20.PDF) into a url that the webviewer accepts using this:

```
let safeURL = win .Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc (your native url);
```

you can also follow this link: [where was file location downloaded in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990069/where-was-file-location-downloaded-in-ionic)

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers normally don't allow JavaScript pages to load local files from the local environment. Your option for this is to either use local paths if possible to run or to create a local server that access and serve the file to the client side.